# How can I have my script only activated on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, responsive

I have a search which I want to jump to the top on focusing but only for mobile users.

How can I set the width by myself?

This is my code so far:

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('input, textarea').offset().top - 10) }, 1);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the matchMedia method:

https://caniuse.com/matchmedia

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($('input, textarea').offset().top - 10)
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ju6k3grm/2/

Comment: @Albeld, could you elaborate what is not working? The mobile detection, or the scrolling to top code you provided?

Comment: @Albeld here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ju6k3grm/2/ I moved the size check into the focus function so it also works if the user resizes his browser to a smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
let isMobile = false;

if ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    isMobile = true;
}

$('input, textarea').focus(function () {
    if (isMobile) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('input, textarea').offset().top - 10) }, 1);
        return false;
    }
});
```